# How much of a gold bonus does the Explorer's Helmet give for revealing every encounter?

Tags: hand-of-fate

The description for the Explorer's Helmet says that it grants a gold bonus for revealing every encounter on a level. How much of a gold bonus does it provide?

[image: Explorer's Helmet in a shop]